# jQuery slideDown erases number of last inserted list item?

Tags: jquery

Hey all.  I have a bit an issue.  I have an ordered list with a series of pre-populated list items.

```
<ol>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

When I add another list item dynamically with jQuery, and slide the element down, it will display the item, but not the number.  Resulting in something like this:

```
1. Item 1
2. Item 2
3. Item 3
4. Item 4
Item 5
```

The jQuery to do this is:

```
$("ol").append("<li>Item 5</li>");
var l = $("ol").children("li:last");
l.hide().slideDown(1000);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, unfortunately, there must not be an easy, elegant way to accomplish this.  After some more tweaking, I came up with another solution that might suffice:

```
var ol = $("ol");
ol.append("<li>Item 5</li>");
var l = $("ol").children("li:last");
var h = ol.height();
l.hide();


ol.animate({
   height: h
}, 1000, function() {
   l.fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Append the item, get the new height, hide the new list item, animate to the new height, and then fade in the new list item.  Seems a little hacky, but appears to work to a similar extent.  Maybe this is going a little overboard with the animations here.

Answer (score 1):

The `slideDown` changes the display on the list item to `block` when it is finished.  This is needed for the height and width animations to work.

You could fix it by doing this:

```
$("ol").append("<li>Item 5</li>");
var l = $("ol").children("li:last");
l.hide().slideDown(1000, function() { $(this).css("display",""); });
```

But this seems less than ideal because it waits until the end of the animation.

Comment: Ah of course, and *block* would ruin the way the list is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable, [fadeIn](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeIn) works. I ran into the same kind of issue with tables/table rows - animation can get pretty messed up on tables (and apparently ordered lists!), but the fade functions seem to work.